# How to get to know which imageView is in Scrolling State in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

There are thousands of images in List(implemented using `RecyclerView`). I want to set images on `ImageView` while image is not in Scrolling state. How will I get particular `imageView` is in scrolling state or not. Because while I'm trying with

```
mListView.addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView view, int scrollState) {
                    if (onScrollListeners != null) {
                        if (onScrollListeners.size() > 0) {
                            for (OnScrollListener listener : onScrollListeners) {
                                listener.onScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
                            }
                        }
                        if (scrollState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                            mAdapter.setScrolling(true);
                        } else {
                            mAdapter.setScrolling(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

Some views got missed. And image doesn't bind at all even after stop scrolling. I'm setting image using GLide Library.

Comment: Why are you trying to set the image when the imageview is not scrolling ? Can you let me know what problem will you solve by doing this ?

Comment: Because i'm pissed with some performance while, user scroll list too fast then, all images hit the url to fetch image from server and whenever image downloads, it will set to imageView even if user is continuously  scrolling, which block my UI thread, which is not needed at all. So i want to stop this blocking of UI thread.

Comment: If you are using glide then it automatically gives priority to those imageviews which are visible on the UI. Image downloading is done on the background thread by Glide. Also viewholder only holds the view references. Content is set each time when that view becomes visible on the screen using bindViewHolder.

Comment: No, glide doesn't ensure exact views.

Comment: I am not saying glide loads the exact views which comes on screen but if user scrolls fast then the priority to load the image which becomes available on screen is higher than  the other ones

Comment: `it will set to imageView even if user is continuously scrolling,` Do you mean that the image is set even if the image view is not in view anymore? Or used at a recycled position? Please post the code where you are doing so.

Comment: I'm just setting the image in onResourceReady() Method. Nothing else i'm doing there. I'm not able to post whole method here.